# Getting all datas from xml through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
<graph>
  <categories>
      <category>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Rows/row/@Date" />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </category>       
    </categories>

  <dataset>
      <xsl:attribute name="seriesName">
        <xsl:value-of select="Rows/row/@Actual_Amount"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </dataset>

  <dataset>
    <xsl:attribute name="seriesName">
      <xsl:value-of select="Rows/row/@Threshold"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </dataset>

  <dataset>
    <xsl:attribute name="seriesName">
      <xsl:value-of select="Rows/row/@Forecast_Amount"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </dataset>

 </graph>
</xsl:template>
```

This is my result:

```
<graph>
 <categories>
   <category name="2014-01-01"/>
 </categories>
 <dataset seriesName="1800.0000"/>
 <dataset seriesName="500.0000"/>
 <dataset seriesName="2800.0000"/>
</graph>
```

Can anyone tell me why am I getting only the first data of my many XML please?
I have tried putting `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` too... but only my first data is generated. please help.

Comment: Please show your input XML.

Comment: And your *expected* output. Do you expect several `graph` elements?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your XML looks something like this:

```
<Rows>
    <row Date="2014-01-01" Actual_Amount="1800.0000" Threshold="500.0000" Forecast_Amount="2800.0000" /> 
    <row Date="2014-01-02" Actual_Amount="1850.0000" Threshold="550.0000" Forecast_Amount="2850.0000" /> 
</Rows>
```

You are only getting the first data because you start off by matching the "document node"

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

This will only be called once, so all your code in the template is only being output once. Additionally, where you do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="Rows/row/@Date" />
```

The **value-of** statement will only return the value of the first node it finds that matches, regardless of how many rows there are.

You probably want to change your first template to just this

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Rows/row" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then change your existing template to match **row** instead...

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <graph>
       ...
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Rows/row" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <graph>
        <categories>
            <category name="{@Date}" />
        </categories>
        <dataset seriesName="{@Actual_Amount}"/>
        <dataset seriesName="{@Threshold}"/>
        <dataset seriesName="{@Forecast_Amount}"/>
    </graph>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note the use of Attribute Value Templates in outputting the **name** and **seriesName** attributes. The curly braces `{ }` indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

Also note that within the template that matches **row** the xpath expressions will be relative to the current **row** node you are matching, so you only have to do `@Date` for example, and not `Rows\row\@Date`

If this is not quite the output you want, please edit your question to show what you actually expect, but hopefully this should point you in the right direction.